# arrow of popover controller has wrong position

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, popover

I have a `NSToolbar` with some items.
One of the item has a link to another `viewcontroller` (popover)
If I click on this item, the view controller will shown as a popover view controller - like this:

[image]

But here you can see that the arrow of my popover is over the label of my item. How can I set the position of my arrow under the label?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: there is no code for this. It was only realize in storyboard. toolbar item drag to view controller and set "popover"

Comment: What is NSWindowToolbar?

Comment: sry i mean NSToolbar in my WindowController ^^

Comment: To my knowledge, there's nothing you can do about it.  A possible workaround is to lay a sheet of NSView and add a label to it.

Comment: I have another approach for this, because I used pop over and I used it on the nsbutton action. if you want....

Comment: can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do that!

using this code

```
@IBAction func info(_ sender: NSToolbarItem) {
    let popover = NSPopover()
    popover.behavior = .semitransient
    popover.animates = true
    let button: NSButton = (sender.value(forKey: "button") as? NSButton)!
    
    let vc = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(identifier: "InfoViewController") as InfoViewController
    popover.contentViewController = vc
    popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds,
                 of: button,
                 preferredEdge: .maxY)
}
```